# Git-p4 on a Perforce stream

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4, perforce-stream

I think I probably know the answer already, but perhaps someone can either help, or give a knowledgeable "no".

I've been using git-p4 to work on a Perforce depot (syncing, editing, submitting) for a long time, on the main branch. I now want to work in a stream. I tried using all the git-p4 options for branches (the docs don't mention streams but I'm trying to treat them the same). I also tried just doing a `git p4 clone //depot/streamname` but that tells me `No changes to import!` and quits instantly.

I found two projects that are forks of git-p4 to support streams, each a few years old, and each unable to submit back to the depot, so they're no good.

I can't change to use branches instead of streams, as the rest of the team want to use streams, and supporting my unusual workflow isn't a good reason to change (even if I am in charge!).

Is there really no option available other than actually using Perforce here? I hate it with a passion, and I would much much rather use git (or anything else!).

Comment: I have no experience with P4 streams, but from what I understood at the time it's their take on distributed development by making everyone run p4d. If that is the case, have you tried to fool git-p4 using different P4PORT settings? Sorry if this doesn't help.

Comment: What happens if you run "git p4 clone -v //depot/streamname" ?

I've just tried on a test stream and that worked fine, but this is also the first time I've ever used p4 streams.

It might turn out to be something easy to fix.

Comment: Thanks @Luke - I tried on another stream today and it does seem to work now. I think before I was trying this on a virtual stream - as I just tried on a virtual stream again today and it still fails (says the depot path contains no files). It's a shame git-p4 doesn't import streams as git branches, like it sounds like it does with p4 branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about git-p4, but you could use Git Fusion to enable you to work with the streams.

This is not a client side product like Git-P4, so if you have multiple Git Users who want to work with streams of depot paths, they can take advantage of it.

More details about using it with streams are here:
  https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/git-fusion/#Git-Fusion/section_j4q_gtx_nm.html%3FTocPath%3DSetting%2520up%2520repos%7C_____11

Comment: Seems like the only realistic option really! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

My use-case was a little different, but very similar to the original question.  My use-case was basically to take commits made to specific files in Perforce and push them to a Git repo.  I attempted to use streams for this, to narrow the scope of the depot, but that didn't seem to work either.

This isn't as graceful, but I did workaround this issue.  The root cause is that the `git-p4` plugin uses the `p4 files` command to get files from the depot, and that command doesn't work on streams, only depot paths.

I worked around this by first creating a client that filtered the depot based on what my stream would have been.  This isn't a 1:1 of what a stream would do, but it was functional for my use case.  I then set the view of the client to mimic what my stream would do:

```
$ p4 client -o git_repo | sed "s#//depot/... //git-repo/...#//depot/main/test/gitfiles/....json //git-repo/....json#g" | p4 client -i
$ git p4 clone --use-client-spec //depot/main/test/gitfiles/...
```

This seemed to do the trick, and got me just the files I wanted, and I was able to move forward.  Like I said, it's not graceful, and it's not a 1:1 of the stream functionality, but it might help someone struggling with how to use the `git-p4` plugin.

https://www.perforce.com/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/p4_files.html